# Create a view that summarize vehilce owned from two tables cars and bikes

Tags: postgresql, view

I have 3 tables owner, car and bikes where car and bike are dependent on owner.

**owner**(_name,_ssn)

**cars**(_ownername,_ownerSSN, model)

**bikes**(_ownername,_ownerSSN, model)

I want to create a view that shows how many cars and bike I own
in the following way

vehicle_owned (_name, _ssn , vehicleamount)

where vehicle amount is car and bikes summarized.

I've tried using count with join on the tables but nothing seems to work

Comment: what means ssn?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: do you expect the whole view script or only the select command?

Comment: I have answered this question to the best of my ability but I regret working on it. You need more information see the questions in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as you should not provide information enough about your table schema, I've improvised this one:

```
create table _owner(_name text, _ssn text);
create table _cars(_ownername text, _owner_ssn text, _model text);
create table _bikes(_ownername text, _owner_ssn text, _model text);
insert into _owner values
  ('me' ,'1'),
  ('you','2');
insert into _cars values
  ('me', '1','Ferrari Modena 360'),
  ('me', '1','Porsche Macan'),
  ('you','2','peugeot 205');
insert into _bikes values
  ('me', '1','Specialized Tarmac'),
  ('me', '1','Pinarello Dogma'),
  ('you','2','Scott Silence');
```

You can use COUNT and GROUP BY to get your desired result:

```
select o._name, o._ssn, 
       ((select count(*) from _bikes where _bikes._owner_ssn = o._ssn)
       +
       (select count(*) from _cars where _cars._owner_ssn = o._ssn)) as total_cars_and_bikes
from _owner o
;


+-------+------+----------------------+
| _name | _ssn | total_cars_and_bikes |
+-------+------+----------------------+
| me    | 1    | 4                    |
+-------+------+----------------------+
| you   | 2    | 2                    |
+-------+------+----------------------+
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/UZMF16252

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something along these lines should work.

```
with 
carcount as (select count(*) cnt, _ownerSSN from cars group by _ownerSSN),
bikecount as (select count(*) cnt, _ownerSSN from bikes group by _ownerSSN),
select _name, _ssn, coalesce(cc.cnt, 0) + coalesce(bc.cnt, 0) vehicleamount 
from owner left join carcount cc on owner._ssn = cc._ownerSSN
           left join bikecountcount cc on owner._ssn = cc._ownerSSN
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use underscores in your names as initial characters. yuck.

You're not thinking about this problem right. It's actually simpler than that...

```
create table _owner(_name text, _ssn text);
create table _cars(_ownername text, _owner_ssn text, _model text);
create table _bikes(_ownername text, _owner_ssn text, _model text);
insert into _owner values
  ('me' ,'1'),
  ('you','2');
insert into _cars values
  ('me', '1','Ferrari Modena 360'),
  ('me', '1','Porsche Macan'),
  ('you','2','peugeot 205');
insert into _bikes values
  ('me', '1','Specialized Tarmac'),
  ('me', '1','Pinarello Dogma'),
  ('you','2','Scott Silence');
```

First you need all the `_cars` and `_bikes`. Because you don't need any information about them, this will work.

```
SELECT _owner_ssn
FROM _cars
UNION ALL
  SELECT _owner_ssn
  FROM _bikes;
```

Doesn't get easier than that. Now if you don't need the _owners which have 0 cars and 0 bikes you can just do

```
SELECT _owner_ssn, count(*) AS cars_and_bikes
FROM (
  SELECT _owner_ssn
  FROM _cars
  UNION ALL
    SELECT _owner_ssn
    FROM _bikes
) AS t
GROUP BY _owner_ssn;

 _owner_ssn | cars_and_bikes 
------------+----------------
 2          |              2
 1          |              4
(2 rows)
```

The rest is question ambiguity

1. Why are you storing the owner_name on the owner and the cars and the bikes? Shouldn't it just be on the owner table?
2. What if two different cars and bikes have different owner names?