# Select a table without a specific row

Tags: postgresql, select

I want to select a table without a specific row. Eg. the table below

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT name, ssn, location
  FROM ( VALUES 
    ( 'peter' , 1, 'Canada' ),
    ( 'peter' , 2, 'Canada' ),
    ( 'anna'  , 3, 'Canada' ),
    ( 'sven' ,  1, 'France' )
  ) AS t(name,ssn,location);
```

If I query SELECT name,ssn from **TABLE**

I want to  receive

```
name | ssn | location|
peter| 2   | Canada  |
anna | 3   | Canada  |
sven | 1   | France|
```

I tried doing SELECT name, ssn from **TABLE** WHERE name != peter but then I wont get peter 2 either. Also if I do ssn != 1 I won't get Sven

Comment: (1) could you give some input back on the last question you asked... http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165897/create-a-view-that-summarize-vehilce-owned-from-two-tables-cars-and-bikes/166008#166008 (2) could you put some more effort into formatting these questions with DDL. (3) can you explain why you want peter with an _ssn 2 over peter with an _ssn of 1?

Comment: I don't know what kind of input you expect, I already chose the best answer that solved my problem. I'm sorry for having a terrible format I'm still learning how to properly use this website. This is because the user that will use this query will be peter 1 in this case, and he is not interested about himself

Comment: You're not explaining your problem sufficiently. We need to know why you want one anna, and one peter (here) and why you're choosing the one peter to be ssn=2, and not ssn=1. The question is otherwise ambiguous. In the other question I gave you two questions and alerted you as to why your question was ambiguous.

Comment: ok now we're making progress why did you choose peter=2 over peter=1, does it matter?

Comment: Now you added another data point, and there is an additional question (still noting you haven't answered the last one) why did you pick Sven with an ssn=1, over peter with an ssn=1. And, why is Sven from France in the output and Canada in the input (assume typo).

Comment: The primary key consist of the location and their SSN ( social security number).  Choosing the person doesn't matter but the person querying is supposed to get a table with the result with himself excluded.

Comment: How does the query know whomever is making the query? That's meta data locked in the connection info. I mean you could do that, but none of that is evident in the question.

Comment: This will be queried inside of a trigger that is triggered when we update the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it appears you goal is to bring back the records that meet your basic criteria (`location = 'CANADA'`), but to exclude the record belonging to the current user.

So, what you would need to do is exclude records for the current user, based on their unique identifier.

If the current user is uniquely identified by `ssn` and `name` (which, based on what's provided, we must assume), then the query should be:

```
SELECT name, ssn, location
FROM foo
WHERE location = 'Canada'
   AND NOT (ssn = 1 AND name = 'peter')
```

(Obviously, you would be likely to replace the literal values in the `WHERE` clause with variables, if this is to be used by multiple users).

UPDATE: Further comments indicate that the unique identifier of the user may be `location` and `ssn`; however, the sample data and query provided don't seem to line up with that. Still, if that is correct, then `location` (and a matching literal) would replace `name` in the `NOT` expression in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I didn't know you could write AND NOT in postgresql. Thanks for the quick and simple solution. And yes I just changed name to location. The data is not correct because Evan Carroll is editing my question with wrong info

Comment: @sazuki how is it exactly what you need? You explicitly choose an answer that says `location = 'Canada'` and in your question you changed it now so that your desired output has Sven with a `location = 'France'`. **Stop running away from your questions and tells us what you want**. If you want in your output `sven | 1   | France|` Then you *must* un-choose this answer or clarify. It is simply incorrect. And, I'm the lone-upvote on this answer because he worked with your quesiton and I applaud @RDFozz's efforts.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: Thanks for the edit; I'd copied the SQL statement from a sentence in the original post, and had merely edited it to add the (apparently) necessary clause.

Comment: @Evan Carroll I made a mistake, but it doesn't help when you're editing my question while I'm trying to fix it. I got my answer and I will leave it at that. Not sure why you're questioning if his solution worked when you seem to have trouble grapsing the problem I had while others understand it perfectly fine.

Comment: Respectfully, I merely fixed the typo to make this solution, which you chose, work. Now it's again wrong and I'm asking you to defend that edit. Did you mean for Sven to be in France, and if so -- how does this solution satisfy your question? What was wrong with my edit which had Sven in Canada and worked with this solution? http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/166019/revisions

Comment: As he said in his edit,  change name to location. That is what I did and it worked, Reminded that you remove where location = 'canada' from the query

Comment: I'll note that in the current version of the question, there's no reference to `location = 'CANADA'`. I included that in my answer as an example of "basic criteria". Again, based on the OP's first comment on his question, I assumed that (regardless of any other criteria), the goal was for the current user's data to be excluded. The last line in the query is the key for that. I will say that I wasn't sure of my interpretation, hence my statement of my assumptions, and my restatement of the underlying request.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand you want to remove duplicates (the 'peter', 1 row). Easiest way is a grouping query:

```
select name, max(ssn) as ssn, location from foo 
group by name, location
```

If you want the exact ordering specified in your question:

```
select name, max(ssn) as ssn, location from foo 
group by name, location 
order by location, name desc
```